# Shutil Move Dir Goes Missing

Tags: python, shutil, os.path

I am trying to write a short script to make some common tasks I do easier. The goal of the script is that I can point it toward a directory that has a bunch of folders within it. For the sake of my question, the example folders might be titled '123-text', '678-text', and '456-text'. Ideally, the script would match the first couple of characters before the '-' using a list and if there is a match move the entire contents of that folder into a created folder called "Sorted".

I have tested the code when the Sorted directory already exists in the pointed-to directory to run the script on and it works without issue. However, when the Sorted directory does not already exist there is an error in my logic somewhere. It copies all but one of the directories that match Names and the one that it misses but was there goes completely missing.

Can someone explain to me where the flaw is in my code and why the one directory goes missing? I had a feeling it might be that the mkdir command takes time for the OS to execute and that the next like is executed to move the folder before it can even point to the newly created folder, but I tried testing around this using sleep and couldn't resolve it.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

workingDir = str(input("Paste the path to your files: "))
Names = ['123', '345', '678', '910']

for file in os.listdir(workingDir):
    if file == '.DS_Store':
        continue
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
    splitted = name.split("-")
    if splitted[0] in Names:
        Path("Sorted").mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        shutil.move(workingDir + '/' + file, workingDir + '/' + "Sorted")
```

Directory Setup:

- Dir

  - Sub Dir '123-text'
  - Sub Dir '678-text'
  - Sub Dir '456-text'

Directory After Running Script:

- Dir

  - Sub Dir '456-text'
  - Sub Dir 'Sorted'

    - Sub Dir '123-text'
    - Sub Dir '678-text'

Comment: `Path("Sorted")` should be `Path(workingDir) / Path("Sorted")`

Comment: Right.  You're creating `Sorted` at the top level, so the first directory you move is actually RENAMED to `Sorted`, and the other directories are moved inside of it.